# Hibernate EntityManager merge not updating whitespace changes

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to update an existing database entry using Hibernate and PostgreSQL (9.5) so that white space is trimmed from strings. For example ...

```
...
EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
...
GeoLocationLocale geoLocationLocale = existingLocales.get(id);
geoLocationLocale.setLocale(geoLocationLocale.getLocale().trim());

long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
geoLocationLocale.setUpdatedAt(new Date(now));
entityManager.merge(geoLocationLocale);
...
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

Else where in my code I successfully update other fields, for example the updatedAt time field in the example above. However, I cannot remove trailing white space from the locale field. I could, if I wanted to change the locale field to something else entirely, for example using something like this ...

```
geoLocationLocale.setLocale(new BigInteger(16, new Random()).toString(10));
```

This will change the locale value. I just cannot remove white space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need more info (ex Entity and Schema Data Definition).
check if it uses a char instead of varchar in Schema.
if it uses char it would have same length appended with empty space.

Comment: Oh nice! That's it. The locale field is character(8) as opposed to varchar. Thanks! Will accept